# Command line download manager that supports batch descriptors to download multiple files?

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, download-manager, aria2

In the Firefox plugin donwloadthemall if yo use the batch descriptor, let's say `http://.../image[000:999].gif`, will start downloading all files:

```
image000.gif
image001.gif
image002.gif
...
image0997.gif
image0998.gif
image0999.gif
```

What command line download manager supports batch descriptors to download multiple files like I just described?

I mention that I tried to scan the man page of aria2c and didn't find the option I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aria2 can do this if the `-P` option is passed. 
From [the man-page](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/manual/en/html/aria2c.html):

> `-P, --parameterized-uri[=true|false]`
>
>   Enable parameterized URI support.
>   You can specify set of parts:
>   `http://{sv1,sv2,sv3}/foo.iso`
>   . 
>     Also you can specify numeric sequences with step counter:
>   `http://host/image[000-100:2].img`
>   .  A step counter can be omitted.  If all URIs do not point to the same file, such as the second example above,
>   `-Z`
>   option is required.  Default:
>   `false`

For the example in the question, the command would be:

```
aria2c -P http://…/image[000-999].gif
```

Comment: I guess I was searching the wrong keywords, thanks +1/accept